# Styling not loading correctly online

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress website on my local machine (vagrant homestead). It works perfectly, all the styling is loaded.

But when I place this online, the theme doesn't work correctly. Console is not showing errors (only warnings). [This](http://empteezy.speis.be/) is the online version.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: different machines render stuff differently, crazy I know, just apply fixes to live site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information provided, I would say the stylesheet directory is incorrect or perhaps being overridden by something else.  The order of your stylesheets can affect this as well.  If this doesn't help, upload a screenshot of all your stylesheets you are including so we can find out which one isn't loading and why.